# how to restrict entry of duplicate object in core data

Tags: ios, swift, validation, core-data, duplicates

How can i restrict duplicate entry in core data

```
//MARK:- save in core data
let appDel1:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel1.persistentContainer.viewContext
let userObj:NSManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "RPAData", into: context)
                
userObj.setValue(rpaType, forKey: "rpatype")
userObj.setValue(rpaReg, forKey: "rparegistration")
userObj.setValue(identificationNumber, forKey: "identificationnumber")
userObj.setValue(rpaTypeId, forKey: "rpatypeid")
                
                do{
                    try context.save()
                    print("rpaReg , identificationNumber , rpaTypeId and rpaType Saved in core Data...")
                } catch {
                    print("Error in save - ", error)
                }
```

If the combination of all the 4 entries(rpaReg , identificationNumber , rpaTypeId and rpaType) are same than these data will not save in core data and an alert will be shown.

this is how i fetch data from core data

```
var dataArray:[NSManagedObject] = []

let appDel1:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel1.persistentContainer.viewContext
let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "RPAData")
            do
            {
                dataArray = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
            } catch {
                print("error =>",error)
            }
```

Comment: You can add a constraint in the Core Data model for that entity so you get an error if you try to save a duplicate, you can have a fetch request with a predicate using those 4 attributes to check that the object doesn't exist or even make the entity conform to Equatable and check against all fetched objects before saving. So there are several options available, the two first are most likely the best options.

Comment: i dont have much knowledge of coredata...can you help me with full coding part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add some constraints in your entity
[image]

Then use this to show error when saving failure (default value)

```
context.mergePolicy = NSErrorMergePolicy
```

Comment: I dont want to show error i want to show alert

Comment: @Sarthak do whatever you want in catch block

Comment: my app got crashed after using this 
this is the error--

constraint violation during attempted migration